# Disqus iframe transparency won't work on Chrome 87

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, iframe, disqus

After upgrading to Chrome 87, I noticed that Disuqs background transparency is not working on a dark theme - the background and text are white so the discussion is unreadable.

As the text is set to white it means that Disqus recognizes the dark theme but the transparency of the background won't work.
I can see the `allowtransparency` attribute is set:
[image]

This works fine on older versions of Chrome and Firefox:
[image]

On the other websites, I can see that disqus has no problems with the dark theme on Chrome 87.

Anyone had such a problem? Anyone know how to solve this?
Unfortunately, I can't count on Disqus support because they don't answer emails and on their forum my post about this problem has been recognized as spam for no reason.

EDIT:
I have now found that this meta tag is causing this problem: `<meta name="color-scheme" content="dark light">`

Can this problem be solved without removing this meta tag?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok... I've found a solution.
This meta tag caused the problem: `<meta name="color-scheme" content="dark light">`

I removed it and instead added CSS code like this:

```css
:root {
  color-scheme: light dark;
}

iframe {
  color-scheme: light;
}
```

https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4772

Comment: @Rafaucau Thank you for sharing your solution! I had this same problem and this fixed it. However, I am still wondering *why* it fixed it. If, for example, in your code you change the color-scheme to dark for iframe, it will render using a white background. According to the w3c thread you linked, it seems to me the background should instead be dark. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Eaton in this comment you see why iframe gets transparent background when color-schemes mismatch: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4772#issuecomment-591553929

> If the color scheme of an iframe differs from embedding document iframe gets an opaque canvas bg appropriate to its color scheme

Comment: This works for me, however, I am curious if anyone has a solution that works with theme toggling (after the iframe loads)?

Answer (score 3):

The correct solution is to add the color-scheme support css fragment to both the parent document and the iframe document. This is because the css fragment tells the browser that both light and dark mode are implemented for the document to which the css is applied. It doesn't say anything about the support for documents embedded in an iframe within that document.

```
/* Apply this css fragment to both parent.html and iframe.html */
:root {
  color-scheme: light dark;
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, however disqus is a 3rd party and at this time it doesn't add color-scheme, this is why another answer is accepted.