# Issue in overriding color-scheme of iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, color-scheme, darkmode

I'm developing website, which using an iframe to show a 3rd party html page and this page has some minimal prefers-color-scheme CSS media queries to switch between light or dark colour background (code shown below).

**I want:**

In my application, I'm not using any light/dark theme and **want show 3rd party html page (in Iframe) always in light theme irrespective of OS dark/light mode settings** (I'm using Mac OS Ventura in dark mode + Chrome 111.0).

**Problem:**

I've tried multiple ways to achieve this including [link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65260505/disqus-iframe-transparency-wont-work-on-chrome-87/65313819#65313819) and [link-2](https://sergeyski.com/css-color-scheme-and-iframes-lessons-learned-from-disqus-background-bug/), unfortunately didn't work well, getting iframe in dark mode.

I've explored other stackoverflow Q&A's as well, but many of them  utilising *color-schema meta tags*, which is not viable in my case.

```html
<!--  My html page, which embedding the 3rd party html page in iframe. -->

<style>
  figure {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 1em 0;
    border: thin dashed gray;
    /* experiment-1 adding to the parent element */
    color-scheme: light;
    color-scheme: only light;
  }
  
  iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10em;
    background-color: white;
  }
  /* want to show iframe always in light mode*/
   :root {
    color-scheme: light;
    color-scheme: only light;
  }
  
  @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    /* want to show iframe always in light mode*/
    iframe#test {
      color-scheme: light;
      color-scheme: only light;
    }
  }
</style>

<h2>Iframe src with always-light mode wanted</h2>
<figure>
  <iframe id="test" src="http://localhost:8000/iframe.html"></iframe>
</figure>
```

```html
<!--  3rd party html page, contains media query for color scheme,
 and displays bg/color based on it-->

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
        :root {
          --bg-color: #0a0524;
          --main-color: #fff;
        }
      }
      @media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
        :root {
          --bg-color: #fff;
          --main-color: #0a0524;
        }
      }
      :root {
        color: var(--main-color);
        background-color: var(--bg-color);
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <b>
      <p>Some heading</p>
    </b>
    <p>Important Information</p>
    <p>Important Information para</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Always ignoring Iframe's color-scheme, and using OS Settings via prefers-color-scheme media query]

As shown in above picture, chrome is always ignoring Iframe's `color-scheme:light` set by parent, and applying `@media(prefers-color-scheme:dark)` media-query.

Please note, My OS is **running in dark mode** (Mac OS Ventura, Chrome Version 111.0).

**My question** is how I can forcefully apply CSS color-scheme to iframe from parent?

Please share your thoughts. Any suggestions/comments are also welcome.

Thanking you in advance.